# Normalize gradient magnitude to unit length in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, gradient, normalize

How can we normalize the gradient magnitude to a unit length in tensorflow?

I am trying to do something like

`gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, _params)
 gradients_norm = tf.norm(gradients , name='norm')
 final_gradients= [(gradients/gradients_norm , var) for grad, var in gradients]`

Any clue? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There are some Gradient Clipping functions that do what you want in one step:

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Gradient_Clipping

For example:

```
tf.clip_by_norm(t, clip_norm, axes=None, name=None)
```

Once you've got your gradients, just as you've shown there, you'll want to use those new, clipped, gradients instead of the original gradients. Use:

```
tf.train.Optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars, global_step=None, name=None)
```

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/train#Optimizers

The `apply_gradients` op should be run instead of the normal minimizer OP to train the network.

Example - the normal training OP:

```
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).minimize(loss_function)
```

Example - your training OP:

```
gradients = tf.gradients(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES), self._loss)
grads_and_vars = [(tf.clip_by_norm(grad, clip_norm), var)  for grad, var in gradients]
train_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-4).apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
```

Note the use of `tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)` which gets you a `list` of trainable variables. These are all the variables the optimizer would normally update by default.